# Игра нарды на Java

Tags: java, алгоритм, разработка-игр

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, можно ли написать игру нарды в настольном приложение! Подскажите, как в java создать доску, фишки и камни для игры?
Опишите, пожалуйста, алгоритм игры нарды или дайте ссылку по разработке игры нарды?

Comment: в качестве примера игрового клиента на чистой Java можно посмотреть [исходные тексты игры "монской бой"](https://github.com/raydac/battleships-resurrection), там и игровое поле и анимаци и фишки и никаких сторонних библиотек в использовании

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Учи java Swing, тебе этого будет достаточно, что бы сделать интерфейс, правила игры, смотри в другом месте, если делать игру - не примитивной, камни, фишки и тд, надо будет нарисовать или стырить =)